# How to have all .Net dlls loaded via Wow64 on a 64 bit machine

Tags: .net, 64-bit

I have a 64-bit machine and a bunch of .Net binaries compiled as Any CPU.  By default they all get loaded as 64-bit.  I thought I remembered a way to set a machine level flag so that all the Any CPU .Net dlls would be treated as 32-bit and not 64-bit by deafult, but I can't seem to find it again.  Can someone please point me in the right direction, thanks.

(I know I could fix each one individualy via CorFlags but I am looking for a machine level setting.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a registry key that is supposed to do this.

See this question:

[Environment variable to force .NET applications to run as 32bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/619155/environment-variable-to-force-net-applications-to-run-as-32bit)

Comment: set the COMPLUS_ENABLE_64BIT environmnet variable to 0.